# Mysql connector cpp symbols not found

Tags: c++, mysql, ld, mysql-connector

I'm trying to compile mysql-connector-cpp on mac os x 10.9.2

I have download last trunk from lp:~mysql/mysql-connector-cpp/trunk and follow this instructions: ftp://ftp.ntu.edu.tw/tmp/MySQL/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-cpp-installation-source-unix.html

But some linker errors with stl occured:

```
Linking CXX shared library libmysqlcppconn.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::runtime_error::what() const", referenced from:
      vtable for sql::SQLException in mysql_art_resultset.cpp.o
      vtable for sql::InvalidArgumentException in mysql_art_resultset.cpp.o
      vtable for sql::InvalidInstanceException in mysql_art_resultset.cpp.o
      vtable for sql::MethodNotImplementedException in mysql_art_resultset.cpp.o
      vtable for sql::SQLException in mysql_art_rset_metadata.cpp.o
      vtable for sql::MethodNotImplementedException in mysql_art_rset_metadata.cpp.o
      vtable for sql::InvalidArgumentException in mysql_art_rset_metadata.cpp.o
      ...
```

Is anybody meet this problem? Is some additional flags is needed?
Thanks.